# Pivot Table or Separate Dynamic Tables?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm doing a inventory management system with a point of sale system. In that project, the owner could create multiple shops as their branches. They want to transfer stocks between shops. To do that, I've to keep track of each item's stock for each shop.

I have thought of making a pivot table and do like shop_id and product_id with stock integer field. But after rethinking it for a moment, I knew that as the shops grow, the records count in the pivot will be multiply by the count of the shops. So that isn't very looking good to me (it's just my opinion). Second way is to create a separate table dynamically like if the admin create a shop with "London Main" as the name, the new table will be created with london_main_products. So, there're will be no more multiplier records problem. But it'll be hard to maintain in future and it does seems more risky than the first option in my eyes. I just can't decide what to do with this problem. Can you please advice me regarding this matter? Please

Comment: what about `inventory` table with location id. And for transfers you can  make a `transfers` table which holds `from` and `to` location id.

Comment: I did the transfers table and transfer_products table for the recording sake. But to handle the actual stock numbers of products, it is a different matter. Making inventory table with location_id is the first way i've thought of but its records can multiple by the count of the shops as the shops grow. Is it really optimal for the long run like 10 years from now?

Comment: It can be optimized even more. Like `inventories` table will only hold the id's and integers which is fine.

Comment: Don't use  a pivot table..backtracking a bit company will have products , stores may have a subset of those products, stores will have inventory which is affected by purchase,sales,transfers,returns and cancellations,products will have prices, sales discounts etc  which may be applicable seasonally or by volume or by store etc.

Comment: I used inventory table which's with location_id, product_id and quantity. Is it good? or any other way?